# What's wrong with this time stamp script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a time stamp script giving the error:
Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")

I have looked into seeing if the problem was on line 1 `function onEdit(e)` and based off of sources I was reading, I can't run this from the script editor. Is line 1 indeed the culprit to this error?

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") //Name of sheet
  {
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Date & Time") + 1; // Name of Column you want to timestamp
    var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf("Input Field") + 1; // Name of Column you want to drop data
    if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == orderCol)
    {
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST","hh:mm:ss aaa"));
    }
  }
}
```

I have a sample sheet here.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NcblMFTVPbKYPmfvh7YnfEHe3dl2QQp6HaC-dqtdiik/edit#gid=0

There are two headers (Column A) Date & Time and (Column B) Input Field.
When Column B is editted, Column A should populate with a time stamp.

Comment: Variable e is undefined. How do you run this method?

Comment: @Konowy I just click the run button inside of the script editor.

Comment: it works for me, not sure if the time showed is correct since that is not my timezone, but it displays the time there

Comment: *"I just click the run button inside of the script editor"*: you cannot expect that to work like that. You should actually trigger the event by editing a cell, otherwise the argument `e` will not be supplied.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. I had a scenario where I did supply the argument initially but, then I discovered that one of the cells I was working with was actually preventing the event from triggering. In this example, rows 19 and 23 never triggered the event. However, when I deleted the Vendor Names (Column B) and re-entered their names, the event triggered. If you leave it the way it is right now, and you try to edit the cell, the time won't show. But delete them, and re-enter, the script will work. What was it about these cells that stopped the event? here is the same sheet with the 2nd scenario.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NcblMFTVPbKYPmfvh7YnfEHe3dl2QQp6HaC-dqtdiik/edit#gid=1950539349

Comment: Konowy and trincot, you guys are spot on. After discovering the actual problem was the cells from the statement above explaining the senario, the script worked the whole time. I will need a better way of preventing this from a cell level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=="Sheet1"){
    var headers = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol=headers[0].indexOf("Date & Time") + 1;
    var orderCol=headers[0].indexOf("Input Field") + 1
    if (dateCol>0 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.range.columnStart==orderCol) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST","hh:mm:ss aaa"));
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing wrong with it.  This takes use of the event object a little more.  Remember, you can't run these functions from the script editor.  They require the event object and without it they  will fail because "e" is undefined.  But the event object provides a lot of useful data.

Try adding `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` to the function like I did in your spreadsheet and you can see all of the data provided by the event object.

Comment: thanks man! Appreciate you taking a look into this. I solved my issue by the statement I made above and discovered that it was specific cells causing the script to not trigger, which is the part I don't understand. But hey, all I had to do was delete them and re-enter the information. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone pointing out the big picture of how this script works. As it turns out, the problem was a set of cells causing the issue. I do not know how to convey the proper answer other than all I did was delete the cells on the 'column to add data' that was giving the issue, re-entered the data and the event triggered perfectly fine. Not sure what was going on with these cells but it appears they were the culprit. I left the sample sheet un-editted to see for yourself.

If you try to type in column B, rows 19 and 23, nothing will happen. If you multi-select 19 and 23 Column B, delete, and enter data, it will work.